# Can I reload a session from a session_id in CodeIgniter?

Tags: session, codeigniter

I want to get a session loaded by the Session class given a particular session id. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to load the data associated to the session for a specific session ID? Why do want to do this? This sounds like a very questionable security issue. A session is always associated to a specific user.

Read the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) to see how to access data for a session. I would not suggest reading different sessions from different users on a request. That's not the purpose of a session. If you really want to have session data available, you can store the session data inside your database (infos on how to do that inside the docs).